# clojure jdbc postgres: Why do the results from my query return unicode characters in table names as �?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, unicode, clojure

My table name is pinkƒpink1, and when I do a select through

```
   (sql/with-query-results res
     "select pinkƒpink1.growth555 as pinkƒpink1$growth555, pinkƒpink1.status_id as pinkƒpink1$status_id, pinkƒpink1.status_position as pinkƒpink1$status_position, pinkƒpink1.i1l0 as pinkƒpink1$i1l0, pinkƒpink1.f∆ as pinkƒpink1$f∆, pinkƒpink1.env_id as pinkƒpink1$env_id, pinkƒpink1.position as pinkƒpink1$position, pinkƒpink1.created_at as pinkƒpink1$created_at, pinkƒpink1.locked as pinkƒpink1$locked, pinkƒpink1.updated_at as pinkƒpink1$updated_at, pinkƒpink1.id as pinkƒpink1$id from pinkƒpink1 as pinkƒpink1 where pinkƒpink1.id in (select * from (select pinkƒpink1.id from pinkƒpink1 order by pinkƒpink1.position asc) as _conditions_) order by pinkƒpink1.position asc"
     (doall res))
```

The results are all messed up:

```
{:pink�pink1$id 1, :pink�pink1$status-position 0, :pink�pink1$updated-at #inst "2013-06-27T21:58:01.711000000-00:00", :pink�pink1$status-id 1, :pink�pink1$growth555 1.3333388822M, :pink�pink1$env-id 1, :pink�pink1$i1l0 YELLL, :pink�pink1$position 0, :pink�pink1$created-at #inst "2013-06-27T21:58:01.712084000-00:00", :pink�pink1$f∆ 55555, :pink�pink1$locked false}
```

Any idea what's going on?  I am on OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: This is probably the same issue/bug as in your previous question. (It could also be a bug in the clojure driver, but I suspect it's unlikely in light of the PG bug you identified.) Link for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353469/postgresql-and-unicode-table-names-why-can-i-not-select-the-table-name-from-the

Comment: .... and your Java, PostgreSQL and PgJDBC versions? What's the database encoding (`SHOW server_encoding`)?

Comment: Oh, and what are you using to *display* the results?

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that the repl is mangling the names when it prints the keywords to the screen. 
perhaps you could try spiting the results to a file an opening it in an editor with unicode support you trust.

also you could try setting `:keywordize-keys false` on the query to prevent this conversion

Answer (score 0):

That's a classic sign of an encoding mismatch or something decoding already decoded / encoding already encoded data.

When you're dealing with encoding problems you really have to trace what's happening step-by-step. This can be really tiresome I'm afraid. You need to identify every point at which an encoding conversion is done and find the one that's mangling the data or misinterpreting it.

This can involve writing driver test cases, using alternative clients to examine data in-situ, etc.

Another possibility is that the result is fine, but the tool you're using to *display* the result doesn't have an appropriate font; it's missing glyphs for the characters, so they show as placeholders.

You should examine the *character codes* for the incorrect characters in the result - the actual binary data. See if they correspond to the correct codes. If they don't, the code that they've been turned into can be a strong clue about the kind of encoding problem you're having.

The most common problems is encoding already-utf-8 text as if it was another encoding like iso-8859-1 ("latin-1"), but that produces a characteristic signature that this problem doesn't have. If it's an encoding issue, this one is more likely to be mismatched 1-byte encodings, like decoding iso-8859-1 text as some other 1-byte encoding. I can't identify *which* other 1-byte encoding (if that is in fact the problem) without having the character codes for the problem glyphs.